# TooManyRequests error. The server is busy. Please try again later

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am using graph API to load huge file (~20MB) and my request is:

```
/v1.0/users/{user-guid}/drive/items/{file-id}/workbook/worksheets
```

And I have an error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "TooManyRequests",
        "message": "The server is busy. Please try again later.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "82d78063-0635-4fac-b5f2-f35cad7ee280",
            "date": "2018-03-14T16:01:34"
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when I use small file placed in the same location.
I can't find any size limitation in the documentation.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a timeout issue with large Excel files. When this occurs it is mistakenly returning an `HTTP 429` result without a [`Retry-After`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling) value.

I don't have an ETA for a fix rolling out but can confirm it is actively being worked on.